# Is there a privacy token implementation in the works for Ethereum like Monero's Tari system?

Tags: tokens, private-blockchain, cryptography, privacy, monero

With the recent announcement of being able to have privacy type tokens on the Monero blockchain. Is there a proposal on ethereum for something similar? The usecase of having a private ERC20 would be useful. What privacy enhancing features have been proposed?

https://www.reddit.com/r/Monero/comments/8lgvw4/introducing_tari_a_decentralised_assets_protocol/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently no. You cannot do privacy tokens on ETH. But maybe in the the future with zk-snarks. More info at https://blockgeeks.com/guides/what-is-zksnarks/